# Why does e.currentTarget.id show a warning?

Tags: dart

Why does e.currentTarget.id show a warning?

```
 void clickHandler(Event e){
   var label = e.currentTarget.id;
```

Comment: _What does the warning say?_

Comment: I think you should post more code. There exists more than one reason for the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

`e.currentTarget` has to be cast in the right type to make the warning disappear.

```dart
void clickHandler(Event e) {
  var label = (e.currentTarget as Element).id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

currentTarget is typed as EventTarget which includes things other than DOM Elements, for example, Window and HttpRequest are also EventTargets.
The warning is because EventTarget does not have an id field or getter.